# Mqtt message into Java Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mqtt, message

I want to populate Java pojo class with mqtt message payload in a spring mvc application. My code is :

```
String messagePayload =  (String) message.getPayload();
ObjectMapper  objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
Test test = null;
    try {
        test = objectMapper.readValue(messagePayload, Test.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

MQTT MessagePayload is `{"name":"abc","age": 32}`, but when It get converted into String in variable *messagePayload*, it shows like {name:abc,age:32}. You see, dropping all double quotes. This when goes to try block throws an error

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('n' (code 110)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: (String)"{name:abc,age:34}"; line: 1, column: 3]
```

I need help in converting the MQTT message into the Java POJO class. Is there another way to do it? Or how can I correct my existing codes?

Comment: What is the Object type of the `message` ?

Comment: And what library are you using.

Comment: public uploadReading(Message<?> message){ codes are here}
Message is generic type. I am using below libraries: 1. Spring-Integration-mqtt-5.2.7
2.org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.2.2

Comment: add also `import ...` part.

Answer (score 0):

MqttMessage.getPayload() returns a byte[]. To convert this into a String object you should use `new String(message.getPayload())`

Comment: I was using Message<?> object, not MqttMessage object. So, message.getPayoad() can be typecast into String such as (String)message.getPayoad().

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. Actually, I was passing the message from cmd (mosquitto is installed in my windows) like
*mosquitto_pub -t whatTopic -m "{"name":abc, "age":32}"*.
In this message was coming in spring mvc application like
*{name:abc,age:32}*. Thus it could not be deserialized into object with Jackson or Gson libraries.
However, when I send the same message with tool MQTTLens the message was coming completely like
*{"name":abc, "age":32}*
Now, this can be deserialized into a java object.
So, I now assume that from the command prompt only string should be sent. If one wants to test an application with JSON format like messages, test with a tool like MQTTLens.

Comment: You have to escape the inner doublequotes like "{\"name\":abc, \"age\":32}". Otherwise they are interpreted/eaten by cmd.